# Import module to namespace class

Tags: javascript, typescript1.7

I need to import external library to namespace class

app.ts:

```
namespace GlobNS {
   class A {}
}
```

mod.ts:

```
import VSTS = require('ExtLib');
namespace GlobNS {
   class B extends ExtLib.ISMTH{
      prop1: string;
      prop2: number;
   }
}
```

ext-lib.d.ts:

```
declare module ExtLib {
   interface ISMTH {
      prop1: string;
      prop2: number;
   }
}
```

But compiler says: 'Property 'ISMTH' does not exist on type 'typeof 'ExtLib''

Also, why it does not works?
[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=namespace%20Test%20%7B%0A%09export%20class%20TestClass%20%7B%0A%09%09constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20class%20TestClass2%20extends%20TestMod.ITestInterface%20%7B%0A%09%09prop1%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09prop2%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20module%20TestMod%20%7B%0A%09interface%20ITestInterface%20%7B%0A%09%09prop1%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09prop2%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you misplaced `implements` with `extends` keyword. Try to change your code to:

```
class B implements ExtLib.ISMTH {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks men )
It works for me. I ll read documentation carefully to do not ask stupid questions.